# Embed a PDF in a pdf document using jsPDF - ReactJs (ES6)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jspdf, html2canvas, jspdf-autotable

Currently I have a table written in HTML.

```
var htmlString = `
<table id="my-table">....
</table> `;
```

I can render this in my react page. I can download the pdf using the following set of codes

```
import React, { useEffect,useRef } from 'react'
import JsPDF from "jspdf";
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'
import html2canvas from "html2canvas";
const htmlDownloader = () => {


const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const HtmlToReactParser = require('html-to-react').Parser;



 const print = async () => { 
   const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
html2canvas(input)
   .then((canvas) => {
     let imgWidth = 208;
     let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
     const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
     const pdf = new JsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
     pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
     pdf.addPage() 
     pdf.autoTable({ html: '#my-table' })
    pdf.save("genv.pdf");
   })
}


   return( 
       <>  <button onClick={print}>print</button>
         <div id="divToPrint" >
     </div>
         
       </>
   )

}

export default htmlDownloader
```

I can achieve the downloading of pdf, but i need to embed a few pdfs in the table. when user downloads the pdf, they can open the pdfs embedded in the table.

Any React packages that can be used?

Comment: maybe this library could help you 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table
according to library document The goal behind this library is to provide a declarative way of defining tables in a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

according to [library](https://npmjs.com/package/@david.kucsai/react-pdf-table) document:
The goal behind this library is to provide a declarative way of defining tables in a PDF.
and this is an example from its document:

```
 <Table
            data={[
                {firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", dob: new Date(2000, 1, 1), country: "Australia", phoneNumber: "xxx-0000-0000"}
            ]}
        >
            <TableHeader>
                <TableCell>
                    First Name
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    Last Name
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    DOB
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    Country
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    Phone Number
                </TableCell>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
                <DataTableCell getContent={(r) => r.firstName}/>
                <DataTableCell getContent={(r) => r.lastName}/>
                <DataTableCell getContent={(r) => r.dob.toLocaleString()}/>
                <DataTableCell getContent={(r) => r.country}/>
                <DataTableCell getContent={(r) => r.phoneNumber}/>
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
```